# How secure/effective is this very short random number generator?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, random

I was experimenting with making my own random number generator and was surprised how easy it was to generate random numbers by doing something like this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    unsigned int number = 1;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 0xFFFF ; i++ ){

        unsigned int * data[0xFFFF];

        number = number << 1;

        number = number ^ (unsigned int)&data[i];
    }

    cout << number << endl;

    while (1);
}
```

My question is, how effective is this, I mean, it seems to generate pretty random numbers, but how easy would it be to figure out what the next number is going to be?

Comment: As written, your program only outputs one number. Is the `cout << number << endl` line supposed to be inside the loop, perhaps?

Comment: Should be posted on [codereview.se], I think.

Answer (score 5):

The addresses of the `data` items are (in practice, because they'll be the same in each iteration) monotonically increasing. They're used as a one-time entropy source. Since they're monotonically increasing they're not a very good source of entropy.

---

In effect, for 32-bit code your code is equivalent to this:

```
auto main() -> int
{
    unsigned number = 1;
    unsigned const entropy = 123456;    // Whatever.
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < 0xFFFF ; ++i )
    {
        number = number << 1;
        number = number ^ (entropy + 4*i);
    }
}
```

---

Regarding

> **”** How easy would it be to figure out what the next number is going to be

as I see it that's not quite the right question for a pseudo-random number generator, but still, it's very easy.

Given two successive pseudo-random numbers *A* and *B*, computing (*A* << 1) ^ *B* yields *X* = *entropy* + 4**i*. Now you can compute (*B* << 1) ^ (*X* + 4) and that's your next pseudo-random number *C*.

---

As I recall pseduo-random number generators are discussed in volume 1 of Donald Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming*.

That discussion includes consideration of statistical measures of goodness.

Answer (score 0):

It's not random at all. not even pseudo,

It has no state and all the input bits are discarded

basically you're pulling some junk off the stack and manipulating it a bit

in many contexts it will always give the same result.